# Join a json UUID value with a column in postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql

I want to join a column with a JSON value. The problem is the `JSON value` is an array and I want to join the resulting UUID value from the other column to whatever matches with the JSON Array. The table name that has the JSON column(column named `staffdep`) is `department` and the other table name is `staff` which has the `staffId` column.

`staffdepID` column's value would be like

```
{"departmentID":[],"staffID":["109ec36a-42bd-42fe-9b1f-c4f479c48fda","109ec36a-42bd-42fe-9b1f-c4f479c48fda"]}
```

`staff id` column would have a unique uuid for each row. For example like '109ec36a-42bd-42fe-9b1f-c4f479c48fda', '84dfbc00-0ff4-4689-98de-1d7496bb9da1'.

The extract of the query I used was,

```
from department d
    join staff s on s.staffId = (d.staffdep -> 'staffID' ->> 0)::uuid
```

The issue with the above query is as I said above, the equivalent UUID of staffID might not always be the first value in the JSON array under d.staffdep. I would need a solution for this.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Use `jsonb_array_elements_text`

Comment: This would be so much easier with a properly normalized data model.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a JSON path condition as the join condition:

```
from department d
   join staff s on jsonb_path_exists(d.staffdep, '$.staffID[*] ? (@ == $id)', jsonb_build_object('id', s.staffid::text));
```